Is there an equivalent of DOM's contain in React, that would also respect portals?
Say we have this code
<div ref={parentRef}>
  <SomeComponent />
  {createPortal(<div ref={childRef}>, domNode, key?)}
</div>

I would like external code to be able to see that those two divs have parent-child relationship.
Clearly parentRef.current.contains(childRef.current) won't work because they are not parent-child in DOM (in general).
However we know that Events do propagate through portals. So that information is indeed stored somewhere inside React.
I was hoping there is something like this, but I wasn't able to find it.
ReactDOM.someMagicContains(parentRef.current, childRef.current)

UPD:
Because React events propagate through portals we could just mark the event itself when it passes through that element and then check it higher in the hierarchy:
const TAG_SYMBOL = Symbol()//can also use WeakMap here
const markEvent = (tag) => (e) => {
  e[tag] = true;
};

...
<div onClick={(e) => {
 // this element can be somewhere very high in the hierarchy
 if (TAG_SYMBOL in e) {
   console.log('Event passed through portal parent');
 }
}}>
  <div onClick={markEvent(TAG_SYMBOL)}>
     {createPortal(<div>Click me</div>)}
  </div>
</div>

However it forces you to use events, more specifically React's events. While the problem looks like it should be orthogonal to events. So I was hoping for a solution that would not use events at all.

I don't think React has this feature, but we can use custom events and React's event propagation system to check if parents and children are connected across portals.

Could you elaborate on this a little?

Tried it. React doesn't seem to export runtime for "SynthticEvent", SyntheticEvent is only an interface, so you can't just do child.dispatchEvent(new React.SyntheticEvent()) hoping to catch it in a parent. And with just new Event('custom') react doesn't seem to care. Portal is ignored for that event.

Can you try something like this? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jolly-leftpad-7lr3z5
Open the console and click on the button, I am thinking we can use the event bubbling nature.

I am not sure I understand. To me it looks like in your example, regardless of whether you put your child component within parent div or not, it will still trigger the same console.logs. Also by passing parentRef to a child component, this example brings the knowledge about parent-child relationship from your own knowledge about the app. I was hoping to make use of React's knowledge of that.
I experimented a little here https://codepen.io/mixtur/pen/gONdKaB?editors=0010. It seems to me that custom events ignore portals.

This however kind of works: https://codepen.io/mixtur/pen/abgRNLW?editors=0010. It is rather ugly though.

import React, { createContext, useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const ParentContext = createContext();

function ParentComponent({ domNode }) {
  const parentRef = useRef();
  
  return (
    <div ref={parentRef}>
      <ParentContext.Provider value={parentRef}>
        <SomeComponent />
        {createPortal(<PortalChild />, domNode)}
      </ParentContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

function PortalChild() {
  const parentRef = useContext(ParentContext);
  const childRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (parentRef.current && childRef.current) {
      console.log('Parent-Child relationship established through context');
      // You can now access both parentRef and childRef here
    }
  }, [parentRef]);

  return <div ref={childRef}>Child in portal</div>;
}

